# Why was my question about an alternative dice toss technique closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878070/java-different-dice-toss-technique

This was closed as not a real question. I was surprised to learn that this question was closed and down-voted even though someone understood my question and was able to respond to my question clearly as I've accepted the answer. I was trying to see two different ways or the approaches to solve the Java code from my code sample.

Learning Java was hard and I've tried my best to ask the question in a clear manner, but someone else may read it differently. I've admitted some question I've a 'limited knowledge' on Java.

Please accept this question that was resolved and I've accepted the answer. I've used Stack Overflow a lot as a viewer and learned a lot. If this question is opened again. I'll rephrase the question.

**UPDATE:**
I've change the title that read: 'Java. Toss one, two or three dice using different Dice toss technique.'
And, I've edited the question that is specific. Please accept this question that was resolved and I've accepted the answer.

Comment: "If this question is opened again. I'll rephrase the question. Thank you." That's not how things work around here. You fix it. *Then* we consider reopening it. But you've asked a variation of that question at least 3 times, haven't you? Maybe you need to read and apply some of the feedback you have been receiving in those questions.

Comment: I strongly suggest a different title.

Comment: Am I allowed to delete one question out of a three question, that was a duplicate. It was my own fault because I tried to be clear but then I've re-posted a question that narrowed down to a specific question.

Comment: Thank you Richard, will a person who have power to open my question accept a change of title or delete one question [out of three]?

Comment: @Irishgirl You are the only one here who will improve your question. I encourage you to do so.

Comment: @Irishgirl Everyone over 3k has the power to reopen questions (5 of them are needed). You make the edits you believe are needed, then the post will automatically be put into a queue for possible reopening.

Answer (score 4):

## Recent Questions

You've had a lot of downvoted questions recently. The commonality amongst them (apart from them having similar subject matter) is that there isn't enough of the right kind of detail.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713117/inputbox-class-and-inputbox-ibox):

> what is the difference between InputBox class and InputBox iBox in
>   simple terms please?
>
> To my understanding is the InputBox class from Javabook and InputBox
>   iBox is a popup screen.

Judging from the comments, the community reacted negatively because:

- The question was ambiguous.
- The question had no code.
- The question didn't demonstrate any effort. This doesn't mean that you didn't expend any effort, but it's not obvious from the question.

There's nothing wrong with novice questions, but they sometimes mean:

- The question is so basic that it would be better covered in a chapter of a book to give it context.
- The question has probably already been answered many times and in many ways.
- The person asking needs to take a step back and learn fundamentals.
- The question may not be a good fit for SO. Not every question (even good questions) are a good fit for SO.

Questions which would benefit from a dialog (chat, or real-world) often don't make for good SO questions.

## The Specific Question

Along those same lines, let's look at the question being discussed:

> Is it possible using the existing code as below, for example Enter 1
>   to toss one dice, Enter 2 to toss two dice and Enter 3 to toss three
>   dice, or 0 to exit? Please show me a smart way to do this? If possible
>   with IF statement?

This question at least has some code, but it suffers from a couple of problems:

- You really didn't demonstrate what you had tried and what didn't work.
- Asking for "smart way to do this" is okay, but without more code or context, it's probably too broad.
- It's fairly localized; your homework/exercise may or may not be useful to anyone else.

And again, the core concepts in the question (loops/conditionals) have already been covered an innumerable number of times.

You may need to take a step back and find additional ways to study the subject matter. As awesome as Stack Overflow is, you can't become a true expert on anything without learning from other means.

Do I think that it deserves the current -11 score? No. I think that it's a poor question, but there tends to be a bit of a "vote bandwagon", which is exacerbated by calling attention to it on meta.

## Don't Give Up!

All that said, the fact that you took the time to phrase a coherent question on meta means a lot. You *have* asked some decent questions. You want to improve your skills and you're willing to accept some criticism and downvotes to get there.

From the questions you've asked and the response you've received, you should have a good sense of the types of questions which are appropriate on SO and how the community will react. Learn from that.

Comment: I'm inclined to disagree with the statement: "_Perhaps most importantly, the actual answer is extremely simple._" I don't think question quality is determined by the answer; rather, the simple answer is indicative of little research effort. Otherwise, good answer!

Comment: You're right; that's not phrased well.